# (un)serialize data classes in python

Tags: python, serialization

I am reading a binary file with `struct` module

```
f = open('myfile', 'br')

struct_fmt = "i6i"
struct_len = struct.calcsize(struct_fmt)
struct_unpack = struct.Struct(struct_fmt).unpack_from
r = struct_unpack(f.read(struct_len))
filetype = r[0]
head = r[1:7]
```

I am wondering if I can do something at higher level, e.g.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Header:
    filetype: int
    head: ### what here? I want an array of 6 integer

header = magic(f, Header)
# or header = Header.magic(f)
```

Then, how to read it from a binary file?

Comment: Where from this `f.read(struct_len)` coming from ?

Comment: it is just a file

Comment: Where ever you have created this `f` you have to include `rb` if reading binary file.